# What is correct dbt profiles for postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, dbt

I have a dbt_project like below.

```
name: 'DataTransformer'
version: '1.0.0'
config-version: 2

profile: 'DataTransformer'
```

Using Postgres, hence I have a profile at `.dbt/profiles.yml`

```
DataTransformer:
  target: dev
  outputs:
    dev:
      type: postgres
      host: localhost
      port: 55000
      user: postgres
      pass: postgrespw
      dbname: postgres
      schema: public
      threads: 4
```

But when I run `dbt debug`, I got `Credentials in profile "DataTransformer", target "dev" invalid: ['dbname'] is not of type 'string'`

I have searched, there are several people has encountered the same error but in different databases. Still not sure why happens in my case

Comment: I’m not sure if this is the reason, but the parameter before it should be password not pass.

Answer (score 0):

I found `dbt debug` to be helpful.  It turns out I had `profiles.yaml` not `profiles.yml` in my project directory.  My config was completely ignored.  The output of `dbt debug` showed me that dbt was looking for `~/.dbt/profiles.yml` (which did not exist).

I also have single quotes around all of the string params in my `profiles.yml` file.